# One CSS class & multiple HTML elements not working with document.querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 5 buttons and I want each of them "reveal" a hidden element on click. At first I used the same class for all 5 buttons:

```
.tae_header-search
```

I used the below code (there is some CSS but as it's not relevant so I'm not posting it):

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  $ = jQuery;

  let toggles, contents, closers;

  function setupToggles() {
    toggles = document.querySelectorAll('.tae_header-search');
    contents = document.querySelectorAll('.tae_header-search-hidden');
    closers = document.querySelectorAll('.tae_header-search-hidden-close');
    toggles.forEach((toggle, i) => {
      if (toggle.classList.contains('toggleIsSetup')) return;
      toggle.classList.add('toggleIsSetup');
      toggle.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        toggle.classList.toggle('toggleIsActive');
        jQuery(contents[i]).slideToggle();
        if (toggle.classList.contains('toggleIsActive')) resizeEvent();
      });
    });
    closers.forEach((closer, i) => {
      if (closer.classList.contains('toggleIsSetup')) return;
      closer.classList.add('toggleIsSetup');
      closer.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        toggles[i].classList.remove('toggleIsActive');
        jQuery(contents[i]).slideUp();
      });
    });

  }
  setupToggles();

});
```

The problem is, that only the first button works - it doesn't work for the remaining 4 buttons. I was thinking adding a distinct class to each button and then adding all the classes to:

```
toggles = document.querySelectorAll('.tae_header-search1,.tae_header-search2,.tae_header-search3,.tae_header-search4,.tae_header-search5');
```

...would resolve the issue. However, with this solution it doesn't work at all. The only solution I was able to get working was to repeat the entire script for each unique class, but this is not ideal since it results in a LOT of code.

Ideally, I'd like to use only one class for all 5 buttons.

Comment: Why are you mixing vanilla JS and jquery?

Comment: Please read the [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and [ask] for guidance on editing your question to make it possible and easy for people to help you.  It will require a **lot** less effort for people who might want to help you (thus making it more likely that they will) if you provided a [mcve].

Comment: That I don't know.. :) It's a snippet I found, I don't know much JS: https://element.how/elementor-show-hide-section/

Comment: This is the kind of thing that jQuery makes extremely easy. If you're using it anyway, that's the thing to do. Also, I suggest that you find another source for code samples.

Comment: The usual approach to stuff like this would be to make use of the relationship the elements have to each other in the DOM. Like, if you had each button and extended text wrapped into an individual parent element - then you would navigate up from the clicked button to that parent, and then select the extended text element _in_ that parent.

Comment: The source is completely fine. And to one person - no need to get all offended and mardy. I simply came to a place I've always known to have a bunch of people who spend their time to help others for free - and we all appreciate it.
  Now in case anyone is looking for the same solution as I am, I got a response from the original website and the following: "jQuery(contents[i]).slideToggle();" needs to be replaced by "jQuery(contents[0]).slideToggle();". Peace.